# How to apply new features to live server and protect database for any misshapen with rollback plan

Tags: php, project-management, production-environment

I am wondering if there is any suitable approach to safely apply new implementation changes or features to my live site, ie- last time when I pushed all the new features after all testings still in live some of my users reported that they face some unexpected things, but not every user is facing that.

So what do I need when I push new changes I can show these changes to only selected group of users so that when any such situation occurs I can rollback/Fix the issue whatever is appropriate. But here is a problem that I do not want the data to be corrupted due to new feature implementation. Because these users maybe selected users but I don`t want any of my user face the inconvenience due to data corruption as my app contains social sites integration like FB, Instagram and Google calendar.

Any help would be appreciated very much, thank you!

Comment: This is a pretty broad topic. Do you have anything more specific in your deployments that is not going right? My best advice off the get go it make deployments small and incremental.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be prepared:

1. Backup your code and download it.
2. Backup your database and download it.
3. Merge your code updates.
4. Update your database schema.
5. Test updating the table(s) whose schema has changed.

If everything goes well you are good to go. If not:

1. Restore your previous code.
2. Restore your previous DB.